# Convergence of Euler product implies convergence of Dirichlet series?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, infinite-product, dirichlet-series, conditional-convergence, euler-product

([Crossposted to Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365905/convergence-of-euler-product-and-dirichlet-series-in-the-same-half-plane)) Suppose we have an Euler product over the primes

$$F(s) = \prod_{p} \left( 1 - \frac{a_p}{p^s} \right)^{-1},$$

where each $a_p \in \mathbb{C}$. The Euler product is convergent in the range $Re(s) > \sigma_c$, and absolutely convergent in the range $Re(s) > \sigma_a$, for some $\sigma_c < \sigma_a \in \mathbb{R}$. If we multiply out the Euler product, we get a Dirichlet series

$$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s},$$

where $a_n = \prod_{p^k || n} a_p^k$ is completely multiplicative as a function of $n$.

**Question: We know that the Dirichlet series for $F(s)$ must converge absolutely in the half-plane $Re(s) > \sigma_a$. Must the Dirichlet series for $F(s)$ also converge in the half-plane $Re(s) > \sigma_c$? If not, what is a counterexample?**

*Edit:* My question is motivated by considering a product like

$$F(s) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^s}\right)^{-1}\left(1 + \frac{1}{3^s}\right)^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{1}{5^s}\right)^{-1}\left(1 + \frac{1}{7^s}\right)^{-1} ... = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{p_n^s} \right)^{-1},$$

where a classical result on infinite series demonstrates convergence for $Re(s) > 1/2$ [although absolute convergence only happens in the half-plane $Re(s) > 1$]. This product for $F(s)$ will have no zeroes in the half-plane $Re(s) > 1/2$, so if we multiply it out to get the Dirichlet series

$$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} - \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} - \frac{1}{6^s} - \frac{1}{7^s}...,$$

does the Dirichlet series converge too? Can we then conclude that the coefficients $a_n$ satisfy

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n a_j = O(n^{1/2 + \epsilon}),$$

for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Your formula for $a_n$ is incorrect if the Euler factors are $1/(1 + a_p/p^s)$. Your factors should be $1/(1 - a_p/p^s)$. The notation $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_c$ are standard for half-planes of convergence of Dirichlet series, not Euler products, so I had to reread your question to figure out what you were actually asking. It is not true that $\sigma_c < \sigma_a$, but rather $\sigma_c \leq \sigma_a$. Is there an actual purpose you have in mind for the Euler product in your motivational example, or is it just curiosity?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365905/convergence-of-euler-product-and-dirichlet-series-in-the-same-half-plane

Comment: @KCd I fixed the factors. The question is specifically about the case when $\sigma_c < \sigma_a$ with a **strict** inequality, because I want to know if the corresponding Dirichlet series also converges in the vertical strip between $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_a$.